# Modal estimate when it comes to project deadlines

Tags: estimation, deadline

I'm relatively new to Project Management (having a technical background) and I noticed that there are these specific columns in an excel file regarding deadlines:

Pessimistic  |  Optimistic  |  Modal  |  PERT  |   Actual

Can someone give me an overview of what these mean (specifically, Modal and PERT) or provide a link to where I can read more about these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PERT is a weighted average of Optimistic (O), Pessimistic (P) and Most Likely (M) estimates:

(O + P + 4 * M) / 6

Check the cells under PERT to see if they have this formula. Probably "Modal" is the "Most Likely" estimate.

Comment: Modal equals MODE average.